# Bobby Fischer Teaches Chess - Visual Teaching of Chess

Tags: books, fischer, websites

I have severe dyslexia which means that for the majority of chess books I find it very difficult to accurately read games (although having a board does help). My favorite chess book when I was younger was *Bobby Fischer Teaches Chess* (which I am sure many of you have picked up at one time or another); its visual style really appealed to someone with my particular difficulties. Is there a series of chess books, or an author/website which uses a similar purely visual method to tackle the more in-depth aspects of chess?

Comment: Have you ever tried any chess DVDs (e.g. from Chessbase) as more visual alternatives to books?

Comment: BTW Chess.com has tons of video lessons of very high quality.

Comment: +1 for Bobby Fischer Teaches Chess.  That was my first Chess book, and I also thought it was very well-done.

Comment: "although having a board does help" you're supposed to have the board next to you 100% of the time when reading chess books

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have yet to receive any answers involving books, perhaps my earlier comment may serve as an actual answer: these days, for those like yourself working through obstacles like severe dyslexia, there is an ever-growing body of video-based chess instruction materials that could be well-suited visual alternatives to typical chess book fare.

Comment: I was hoping for some visual books but this gives me a thinly veiled excuse to get a tablet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you are still looking for books, but if you are there are a couple that fit your bill.

The method that was used in Bobby Fischer Teaches chess is called programmed instruction.

There are two books that use that method. One is called 
The Chess Tutor: Elements of Combinations and the other is called
The Genesis of Power Chess: Effective Winning Technique for Strategy and Tactics. Both are by Leslie Ault.

Leslie Ault was involved in the writing of Bobby Fischer Teaches chess as well.

Answer (score 2):

[Chessable](https://www.chessable.com/) have turned a large number of chess books, many of them classics, into audio-visual chess courses. I think you can register for free to preview their material. Alternatively they have a [YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxVGiP4dl19wwGJlCy3_u8g) which also publishes previews.

Answer (score 0):

Bruce Pandolfini's Chess Movie may work for you. See if you can find a sample.
I used to take it to read after a hike. No board required.